# Making a PHP object behave like an array?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'd like to be able to write a PHP class that behaves like an array and uses normal array syntax for getting & setting.

For example (where Foo is a PHP class of my making):

```
$foo = new Foo();

$foo['fooKey'] = 'foo value';

echo $foo['fooKey'];
```

I know that PHP has the _get and _set magic methods but those don't let you use array notation to access items.  Python handles it by overloading __getitem__ and __setitem__.

Is there a way to do this in PHP?  If it makes a difference, I'm running PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you extend `ArrayObject` or implement `ArrayAccess` then you can do what you want.

- [ArrayObject](http://php.net/arrayobject)
- [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/arrayaccess)

Comment: Very cool.

It doesn't seem like either of those can be used with array functions like array_key_exists, etc.

Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, use offsetExist() method instead.

Comment: Would I do that on the instantiated object itself?

if( $foo->offsetExists('fooKey') ){}

Comment: You can use isset, I believe, but you can't use array_key_exists.

Comment: Cast an ArrayObject as an Array to use it with array functions, e.g. array_values((array) $some_array_object).  It's an annoying extra step, but it works.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13480254/362042) for a multi-dimensional implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, casting just results in a normal PHP array -- losing whatever functionality your ArrayObject-derived class had.  Check this out:

```
class CaseInsensitiveArray extends ArrayObject {
    public function __construct($input = array(), $flags = 0, $iterator_class =     'ArrayIterator') {
        if (isset($input) && is_array($input)) {
            $tmpargs = func_get_args();
            $tmpargs[0] = array_change_key_case($tmpargs[0], CASE_LOWER);
            return call_user_func_array(array('parent', __FUNCTION__), $tmp    args);
        }
        return call_user_func_array(array('parent', __FUNCTION__), func_get_args());
    }

    public function offsetExists($index) {
        if (is_string($index)) return parent::offsetExists(strtolower($index));
        return parent::offsetExists($index);
    }

    public function offsetGet($index) {
        if (is_string($index)) return parent::offsetGet(strtolower($index));
        return parent::offsetGet($index);
    }

    public function offsetSet($index, $value) {
        if (is_string($index)) return parent::offsetSet(strtolower($index, $value));
        return parent::offsetSet($index, $value);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($index) {
        if (is_string($index)) return parent::offsetUnset(strtolower($index));
        return parent::offsetUnset($index);
    }
}

$blah = new CaseInsensitiveArray(array(
    'A'=>'hello',
    'bcD'=>'goodbye',
    'efg'=>'Aloha',
));

echo "is array: ".is_array($blah)."\n";

print_r($blah);
print_r(array_keys($blah));

echo $blah['a']."\n";
echo $blah['BCD']."\n";
echo $blah['eFg']."\n";
echo $blah['A']."\n";
```

As expected, the array_keys() call fails.  In addition, is_array($blah) returns false.  But if you change the constructor line to:

```
$blah = (array)new CaseInsensitiveArray(array(
```

then you just get a normal PHP array (is_array($blah) returns true, and array_keys($blah) works), but all of the functionality of the ArrayObject-derived subclass is lost (in this case, case-insensitive keys no longer work).  Try running the above code both ways, and you'll see what I mean.

PHP should either provide a native array in which the keys are case-insensitive, or make ArrayObject be castable to array without losing whatever functionality the subclass implements, or just make all array functions accept ArrayObject instances.