# creating an array class with php

Tags: php

if i have two arrays i.e

```
$text = 'i am passed :)';
$fn = array(
':)',
':-)',
';;)'
)

$rep = array(
'smily1',
'smily2',
'smily3'
            );

$output = str_replace($fn, $rep, $text);

echo $output;
```

i want to make a class for this to use in future where i will want...
how can i make a class for it...

and also how can i create a function for this...

Comment: I don't really see a technical question here. Why not use the method you've already got? It would be simple to create a class to wrap around this functionality.

Comment: what do you want this class to do? You're looking to create a "class SmileyReplacer"? What's wrong with what you have, and why should it be a class?

Comment: You might also take a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091/making-a-php-class-behave-like-an-array

Comment: Heh.  I didn't remember that was my question.  Not fishing for votes, honest :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically by wrapping your function in a class.  If you're looking for more advanced functionality then that, you'll have to specify.

```
<?php

class SmileyFilter {
  private $_keys;
  private $_values;

  function add($key, $value) {
     $this->_keys[] = $key;
     $this->_values[] = $value;
  }

  function add_all($pairs) {
    foreach ($pairs as $key => $value)
      $this->add($key, $value);
  }

  function replace($text) {
    return str_replace($this->_keys, $this->_values, $text);
  }
}

// usage

$s = new SmileyFilter();

$s->add(':)', 'smily1');
$s->add(':-)', 'smily2');
$s->add(';;)', 'smily3');

/* OR

$smileys = array(
  ':)'  => 'smily1',
  ':-)' => 'smily2',
  ';;)' => 'smily3');

$s->add_all($smileys);

*/


$s->replace('i am passed :)'); // "i am passed smily1"
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class SmileyReplacer
{
    protected static $_map = array(
        ':)'  => 'smiley1',
        ':-)' => 'smiley2',
        ';;)' => 'smiley3'
    );

    public static function replace($string)
    {
        return str_replace(array_keys(self::$_map), self::$_map, $string);
    }
}

// Usage
echo SmileyReplacer::replace('I am happy :)'); // I am happy smiley1
```

I see no reason why this should be instantiated, so an all static class is fine. There is no real state in it. You could add a static method `addMap(array $map)` which you could pass an associate array in case you want to feed the map from outside.

If you are concerned about the calls to `array_keys` each time you run `replace`, do benchmark. I highly doubt you can come up with enough smileys so it would really have an impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

**Smiley**

```
class Smiley {
    private $name;
    private $data;

    public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
    }

    public function getData() {
    return $this->data;
    }

    public function setData($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
    return $this;
    }
    function __construct($name = null, $data = null) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->data = $data;
    }

}
```

**SmileyMapper**

```
class SmileyMapper {
    private $smilies = array();

    public function addSmiley(Smiley $smiley) {
    $this->smilies[] = $smiley;
    return $this;
    }
    public function replaceSmileys($str) {
    return str_replace(
        array_map(
            create_function(
            'Smiley $item',
            'return $item->getData();'
            ),
            $this->smilies),
        array_map(
            create_function(
            'Smiley $item',
            'return $item->getName();'
            ),
            $this->smilies),
        $str
    );
    }
}
```

**Example**

```
$text = 'i am passed :)';
$fn = array(
    ':)',
    ':-)',
    ';;)'
);

$rep = array(
    'smily1',
    'smily2',
    'smily3'
);

$sm = new SmileyMapper();
foreach ($fn as $k => $v) {
    $sm->addSmiley(new Smiley($rep[$k],$v));
}
echo $sm->replaceSmileys($text);
```

Comment: Now that is seriously overengineered, but fun :)

Comment: I thought it would be appropriate on a subject like smileys. :P

Comment: Smiley should implement an interface. Just to make sure. And why not use an SplObjectStorage for SmileyMaper::smileys :) err smiley1

Comment: I also think it could be necessary to implement a templating engine to account for different view requirements. Wouldn't you agree?