# Multidimensional ArrayObject

Tags: php, arrayobject, arrayaccess

Is there a way to implement class with multidimensional array access? I want something like

```
$obj = new MultiArrayObject();
$obj['key']['subkey'] = 'test';
echo $obj['key']['subkey']; //expect 'test' here
```

Comment: This is how the default `Array` behaves. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to implement `Session` class, that will put data to Redis storage and will get it from there. Just like usual `$_SESSION` variable, but with additional features like `session_start()` calls.

Comment: `ArrayObject` does _exactly as you ask_ with _multi-dimensional arrays_ without any extra coding.  Maybe interesting? [PHP ArrayAccess set multidimensional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459399/php-arrayaccess-set-multidimensional/29496048#29496048). I suspect that `ArrayObject` has access to a lot of the 'internal PHP array stuff' and provides it for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax with which a class can intercept *multiple* levels of array access, but you can do it one level at a time by [implementing the `ArrayAccess` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php):

```
class MultiArrayObject implements ArrayAccess {

    protected $data = [];

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        if (!array_key_exists($offset, $this->data)) {
            $this->data[$offset] = new $this;
        }
        return $this->data[$offset];
    }

    /* the rest of the ArrayAccess methods ... */

}
```

This would create and return a new nested `MultiArrayObject` as soon as you access `$obj['key']`, on which you can set data.

However, this won't allow you to distinguish between setters and getters; all values will always be implicitly created as soon as you access them, which might make the behaviour of this object a little weird.

Comment: How to implement `offsetSet()` here?

Comment: `$this->data[$offset] = $value;`...!?