# How to use a PHP object as an array

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

I have a heard time figuring out how to use a class as an array. [This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091/making-a-php-object-behave-like-an-array) helped me a bit on the way; but it doesn't work.

I have a class like this one:

```
class body_text
{
    // class body_text's attributes
    var $position;
    var $content;
}
```

And I want to use it as an array:

```
$body_text_id = 0; 

while ($row['page'] <> "")
{           
    $body_text[$body_text_id] -> position = trim($row["page"]);
    $body_text[$body_text_id] -> content = trim($row["text");
    $body_text_id++;
}
```

Now, it seems I would need to use this for my class

```
class body_text_class extends ArrayObject
```

and use this then:

```
$body_text = new body_text_class();
```

But that doesn't work.

I am sure there is a simple answer to this... but I can't find it. Thanks for any hints!

EDIT: Added another line in the loop to make it clearer. Sorry!
My aim: I get back many bits of text and its position within a website from a first query ("$row['page']"), and I want to store these in a variable for later use.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe it helps to explain your use case.

Comment: The short answer is that your class will have to `implement` the [`ArrayAccess` interface](http://php.net/arrayaccess). The long answer is that it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do here, so a precise answer is not possible.

Comment: I edited my entry. Perhaps it's easier to understand now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to follow the code but you are just showing an array of objects:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $body_text[$i] = new body_text;
    $body_text[$i]->position = 'something';
}
print_r($body_text);
```